# How to obtain the number of features after preprocessing to use pyspark.ml neural network classifier?

Tags: neural-network, pyspark, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to build a neural network using pyspark.ml.
The problem is that I am using onehotencoder and other pre-processing methods to transform the categorical variables. The stages in my pipeline are:

1. indexing the categorical features
2. using Onehotencoder
3. using Vector assembler
4. then I apply PCA
5. giving the "pcaFeatures" to a neural network classifier

But the problem is that I don't know the number of features after the step 4 to give it to "layers" of the classifier in step 5. 
My question is that how can I obtain the final number of features? here is my code, I did not include the import and data loading part.

```
stages = []
for c in Categories:
    stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol= c , outputCol=c + "_indexed")
    encoder = OneHotEncoder(inputCol= c + "_indexed", outputCol=c + "_categoryVec")
    stages += [stringIndexer, encoder]

labelIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="Target", outputCol="indexedLabel")

final_features = list(map(lambda c: c+"_categoryVec", Categories))+Continuous


assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols= final_features,
    outputCol="features")

pca = PCA(k=20, inputCol="features", outputCol="pcaFeatures")
(train_val, test_val) = train.randomSplit([0.95, 0.05])

num_classes= train.select("Target").distinct().count()

NN= MultilayerPerceptronClassifier(labelCol="indexedLabel", featuresCol='pcaFeatures', maxIter=100,
                                    layers=[????, 5, 5, num_classes], blockSize=10, seed=1234)


stages += [labelIndexer]
stages += [assembler]
stages += [pca]
stages += [NN]

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=stages)
model = pipeline.fit(train_val)
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.PCA), the input parameter `k` is the number of principal components.

So in your case:

```py
pca = PCA(k=20, inputCol="features", outputCol="pcaFeatures")
```

The number of features is 20.

**Update**

Another way to do it would be to look at the length of one of the assembled vectors.

For example, if you wanted the length after Step 3:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col
nfeatures = assembler.withColumn('len', udf(len, IntegerType())(col('features'))\
    .select('len').take(1)
```

I feel like there should be a better way to do this, i.e. without having to call `take()`.

Comment: That makes sense! I don't know why I didn't see it. Thanks. Btw, if I am not using the PCA, do you know how can I obtain the number of features from step 3?

Comment: len(final_features) does not work because onehotencoder does not return multiple columns. It is not straightforward with pyspark. Anyways I will keep the PCA for now to complete my task! I guess by mistake I removed your comment. Sorry for that.